# FFLibraryUpgradeLock error while opening iMovie library from another machine

Tags: imovie

I'm getting this error when opening an iMovie library that I copied from another machine. I copied it and overwrote `~/Movies/iMovie Library.imovielibrary`.

> "iMovie Library” could not be opened. You don’t have permission to save the file “FFLibraryUpgradeLock” in the folder “iMovie Library

I have made sure that iMovie has "File access". I even granted iMovie full disk access.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just creating a dummy file called `FFLibraryUpgradeLock` inside the lib directory

`$ touch ~/Movies/iMovie Library.imovielibrary/FFLibraryUpgradeLock`

and then started iMovie. Everything works fine now and I can see all the projects in the old library.